Filter duplicates using unknown columns
public async Task<dynamic> GetDuplicants(params string[] selectedColumns)

{
    
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Applicant), "x");
    var properties = selectedColumns.Select(columnName => Expression.Property(parameter, columnName));
    var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<Applicant, object>>(Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(object), properties), parameter);
    var duplicates = await _dbContext.Applicants
                                .Where(x => x.Deleted== false)
                                .GroupBy(selector)
                                .Select(group => new
                                {
                                    NumberOfApp = group.Count(),
                                    Columns = group.Key                                      })
                                .Where(result => result.NumberOfApp > 1)
                                .ToListAsync();

    return duplicates;

}


could not be translated. Additional information: The query contained a
new array expression containing non-constant elements, which could not
be translated: 'new object[]

I'm expecting duplicates on the specified columns.

Break it into two LINQ queries, once you get the groupedApplicants then do the LINQ Select group in a second query.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Do you need duplicated records or just keys which have duplicates?

@JeremyThompson i tried it but actually it takes a lot of time to retrieve the data

@SvyatoslavDanyliv for now i only i need the keys

It is EF Core or old EF6?

@SvyatoslavDanyliv core

I've made a few adjustments to your function to enhance its flexibility. It now returns a List of DuplicatesInfo with columns converted to strings.
To simplify dynamic query generation, I utilized string concatenation with '|' as a separator to create translatable keys. After materialization, I split the key to retrieve string values.
Here's how you can use the function:
var result = await _dbContext.Applicants
    .Where(x => x.Deleted == false)
    .GetDuplicantsAsync(selector);

And here's the implementation:
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public class DuplicatesInfo
    {
        public string[] Keys { get; set; } = default!;
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }

    public static async Task<List<DuplicatesInfo>> GetDuplicantsAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, params string[] selectedColumns)
    {
        var keySelector = GenerateKeyFunction<T>(selectedColumns);

        var duplicates = await query
            .GroupBy(keySelector)
            .Select(group => new
            {
                Count = group.Count(),
                Columns = group.Key
            })
            .Where(s => s.Count > 1)
            .ToListAsync();

        var result = duplicates.Select(d => new DuplicatesInfo
        {
            Keys = d.Columns.Split('|'),
            Count = d.Count
        }).ToList();

        return result;
    }

    static MethodInfo _stringConcatMethodInfo = typeof(string).GetMethods()
        .Single(m =>
            m.Name == nameof(string.Concat) && m.GetParameters().Length == 2 &&
            m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == typeof(string) &&
            m.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType == typeof(string)
        );


    static Expression<Func<T, string>> GenerateKeyFunction<T>(IEnumerable<string> propertyNames)
    {
        Expression<Func<string, string, string>> concat = (s1, s2) => s1 + "|" + s2;

        var entityParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");

        var keyBody = propertyNames
            .Select(p => (Expression)Expression.PropertyOrField(entityParam, p))
            .Select(p => p.Type == typeof(string) ? p : Expression.Call(typeof(Convert), nameof(Convert.ToString), Type.EmptyTypes, p))
            .Aggregate((prev, next) => Expression.Add(Expression.Add(prev, Expression.Constant("|"),_stringConcatMethodInfo), next, _stringConcatMethodInfo));

        var lambda   = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(keyBody, entityParam);

        return lambda;
    }
}


thank you  i tried diffrent approach and it worked i used sql query instead
